# Size of Application when your Sqlite DB is in App Group

Tags: ios, ios-extensions

I had a application where i am using Core Data and the sqlite file was generated in Documents directory. With iOS8 Apple introduced Extension functionality where data can be share between different apps using Share, Action extension. In this case i had move my SQLite to AppGroup so that items can be saved to SQLite directly.
When my SQLite file was in Documents directory, i was able to see the size of the application from General -> Usage -> Manage Storage and see the application name but when i had moved the SQLite to AppGroup i am not able to see the size of the DB from General -> Usage -> Manage Storage.

So now how can i get total size of the application in Usage or some other place Apple has provided.